# Caesar's box encryption/decryption program

Tags: java

that is a [Caesar's box encryption](http://heap.joshdick.net/caesarbox) for anyone who doesnt know

```
public class CaesarBox {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // CaesarsBox <-encrypt|-decrypt>
    if (args[0].equals("-encrypt")) {
        System.out.println(encrypt(args[1]));
    } else if (args[0].equals("-decrypt")) {
        System.out.println(decrypt(args[1]));
    }
}

public static String encrypt(String plaintext) {
    // TODO put encryption code below this line
    plaintext = plaintext.replaceAll("\\s+", "");// removes white space
    plaintext = plaintext.toLowerCase();// converts capitol letters to lower
    // case

    char[] charArray = plaintext.toCharArray();
    // takes individual characters from the arguments and puts them into an
    // array

    int x = charArray.length; // assigns the length of charArray to x
    int y = 0;
    while (y < x) {
        ++y;
        if ((y == Math.floor(y)) && y * y >= x) {
        // tests if y is an integer
        // increases y until it is an integer
            break;
        }// above code finds the the length of the sides of the box
    }
    char[][] box = new char[y][y];// creates a 2d array
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < box[i].length; j++) {
            if (pos < plaintext.length()) {
                box[i][j] = plaintext.charAt(pos);
                pos++;
            // fills the array with the characters from the text to be
            // encrypted
            }
        } 
    }
    String encrypted = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < box.length; j++) {
            if (box[j][i] != 0) {// tells the program to ignore null values
                encrypted += box[j][i];
            }
            // prints out the letters in the box by column
        }

    }
    return encrypted;

// Put encryption code above this line

}

public static String decrypt(String cyphertext) {
    // TODO put decryption code below this line
    cyphertext = cyphertext.replaceAll("\\s+", "");// removes white space
    cyphertext = cyphertext.toLowerCase();// converts capitol letters to lower case

    char[] charArray = cyphertext.toCharArray();
    // takes individual characters from the arguments and puts them into an
    // array

    int x = charArray.length; // assigns the length of charArray to x
    int y = 0;
   while (y < x) {
        ++y;
        if ((y == Math.floor(y)) && y * y >= x) {
            // tests if y is an integer
            // increases y until it is an integer
            break;
        }// above code finds the the length of the sides of the box
    }
    char[][] box = new char[y][y];// creates a 2d array
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < box[i].length; j++) {
            if (pos < cyphertext.length()) {
                box[i][j] = cyphertext.charAt(pos);
                pos++;
            }
        }
        // fills the array with the characters from the text to be
        // encrypted
    }
    String decrypted = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < box[i].length; j++) {
            if (box[j][i] != 0) {// tells the program to ignore null values
                decrypted += box[j][i];
                // prints out the letters in the box by column
            }

        }
    }

    return decrypted;
    // Put decryption code above this line
    }

}
```

That's my code so far, the problem I'm having is with decrypting things that aren't perfect squares for example "javanoob needs help" is encrypted to joelaodpvbsanhnee but is decrypted to joseodaeepnlvhabn which obviously isnt right. I know the solution is something to do with putting spaces into the array at the right places but i cant figure out how to do it, any help would be amazing! :) if you need me to explain anything just let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are loosing spaces because of this line:

```
plaintext = plaintext.replaceAll("\\s+", ""); // removes white space
```

What you probably wanted to do was to trim spaces from the ends and not all spaces:

```
plaintext = plaintext.trim(); // Removes white space on ends.
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I found about Caesar box, the sum of the total number of characters has to be a perfect square. If you try a message with 25 char in your code, it works fine:

```
The password is Bee ring twice
```

encode mesage:

```
tsdethsirwewsiipobncarege
```

decoded message:

```
thepasswordisbeeringtwice
```

In order to enlarge messages to a perfect square number of chars, you can add a chars in the empty spaces of the box, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < box[i].length; j++) 
    {
        if (pos < plaintext.length()) 
        {
            box[i][j] = plaintext.charAt(pos);
            pos++;
        // fills the array with the characters from the text to be
        // encrypted
        }
        else 
            box[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

and modifying the contruction of the encriptes String, alowing 0 to be included:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < box.length; i++) 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < box.length; j++) 
    { 
            encrypted += box[j][i];
        // prints out the letters in the box by column
    }

}
```